# Is my session schema vulnerable to session fixation?

Tags: php, session-fixation

I have a PHP application, where two session IDs are being used.

I will use `foo` and `bar` as example for those session IDs.

- The `foo` session ID is being generated at the login page.
- The `bar` session ID is being generated after a successful login.

The `foo` session ID is fixed, meaning it's not changing before and after a successful login. The `bar` session ID changes after every login and logout. The session is deleted after logging out.

If any of the session IDs (either `foo` or `bar`) is deleted from the browser, the application redirects the user to the login page.

Is this application vulnerable to [session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) or not?

Comment: Why are you using two session id's and which session ID is privileged?

Comment: Because one SESSION ID is being generated by CMS itself and second SESSION ID is being added by myself (let's assume a CSRF cookie)

Comment: What is both session ID's being used for?

Answer (score 1):

If your CMS is creating the session, don't create another one. If you use `session_start()` somewhere on your custom code, you will use the same session your CMS created.

Don't create another another wheel to replace the professional wheel you already have.